# How set up TXT record for both Amazon SES and Mailgun?

Tags: dns

Currently TXT record for my domain example.com looks like this:

```
TXT example.com.="amazonses:GQxg09o5paN/HJqx2rOIXbEOQuOyOqcH"
```

I want to add Mailgun SPF record:

```
TXT example.com.="v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
```

I can't create two records with same host (name), so how I can combine those two records?

Comment: Who your DNS service provider?

Comment: AWS Route51 is my DNS provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple TXT record on Route53: In "Value" text field paste the first value, press ENTER on your keyboard, then paste the second value:

[image]

After that, this is how the results look:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                      IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.               3600    IN      TXT     "amazonses:GQxgfoobarfoobarqx2rOIXbEOQuOyOqcH"
example.com.               3600    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
```

Comment: @user606521 to be fair, it's right there in the screen shot!  "Enter multiple values on separate lines"

Comment: I know but with every other DNS provider you just create separate TXT records (which in fact ARE separate records) and not edit single input for multiple values...